# Не получается подключить Firebase к Android проекту

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

При попытке подключить Firebase к Android проекту вылетает ошибка: "Build was configured to prefer settings repositories over project repositories but repository 'Google' was added by build file 'build.gradle'".
Путем проверок, я понял, что ошибка выходит из build.gradle в строках

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
}
}
```

В строке

> google()  // Google's Maven repository

При удалении данной строки ошибка не вылетает. Помогите, пожалуйста)

Код build.gradle project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    // ...

    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }

}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Код build.gradle app:

```
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.photo42"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

P.S. Изначально в build.gradle не было allprojects{...}. Добавил сам.

Comment: А зачем вам его к Android Studio подключать? Подключите к проекту приложения. Проблема похоже в Gradle, вот тут ищите ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69794803/5479247

Answer (score 0):

В новой версии ошибка может заключаться в строках

```
allprojects {
    // ...

    repositories {
        // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        // ...
    }

}
```

Удалите их из gradle это должно помочь!